# ASP.NET Core Razor page call COM dll runtime error: COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID, error: 80040154

Tags: asp.net, webforms, com, razor-pages

I had an old ASP.NET webforms project to call COM dll (written in C++, build in win32), and that is OK on my PC.

I start a new project (ASP.NET Core Razor pages, VS 2022) and do the migration from the webform project.

At runtime, I get this error:

> COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {63AC71CD-2774-4B3E-AE85-B1E8DC3CB296}, failed due to the following error: 80040154

But in my old project (same pc), the CLSID is OK and works fine, so what is the difference btw ASP.NET Core Razor page and ASP.NET webforms when calling a COM dll?

I have rebuilt the COM dll and do the registration using `regsvr32 xxx.dll`, but it did not work.

I also searched the registry and the registration is OK

Comment: the application pool "Enable 32-Bit Applications" is already ON

Comment: 80040154 is class not registered so it means for your running code, the class is not registered and as you suspect it's very often a 32vs64 bit issue (client + registry). You can use a tool such as Procmon from sysintenals https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon (filter by registry access) to check what's being really use.

Comment: Force the project to x86 and don't use any cpu. You have to run the project as x32 or you need a x64 bit version of that. Dll

Comment: Albert D. Kallal is right, specify the web application as x86 and the issue is gone